# Cannot set property 'weather' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Putting Json data in a this.variable but I keep getting the error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'weather' of undefined. Does anyone know how to fix this.

```
var currentWeather;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  currentWeather = new CurrentWeather();
  currentWeather.create();
  loadJSON(currentWeather.api, currentWeather.gotData);
}



function draw() {
  background(0);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class CurrentWeather{

 create(){
  let url =       'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=';
  let city = 'Manassas';
  let apiKey ='ApiKeyHere';
  let units = '&units=imperial';
  this.api = url + city + apiKey + units;
   this.weather;
 }

 gotData(data){
   this.weather = data;
 }

}
```

Comment: what is `this.weather;` supposed to do?

Comment: My guess it is scoping issue: `loadJSON(currentWeather.api, currentWeather.gotData.bind(currentWeather));`

Comment: What happens if you had a constructor() {} in your class? What line is the error?

Comment: When I change create() to a constructor I get the same error

Comment: this.weather is a variable that hold the json data from an api

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line `loadJSON(currentWeather.api, currentWeather.gotData);` to

```
loadJSON(currentWeather.api, currentWeather.gotData.bind(currentWeather));
```

You are having scoping issues. `this` is being overridden/lost from your callback methods. In your case `this` supposed to be the instance of `CurrentWeather` which you have as `currentWeather = new CurrentWeather();`. `.bind(currentWeather)` is used to scope `this` to a specific function. Also since the `currentWeather` is defined globally you may need to just use that variable instead of using `this` in some cases. It's hard to tell where other issues are without the full code.

Comment: Perhaps you should add some notes to explain why.

Comment: That seems to fix the error but when I try to call the variable from anywhere but the gotData function it gives me undefined

Comment: @BeanieGod I have updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry about the late response but this was able to fix it thank you

Comment: Great! Your should mark the answer as right answer. @BeanieGod